# Laravel 4 public directory issue

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to get Responsive File Manager 9 working on my Laravel 4 project. I go through the installation process here `http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/index.php` and I put the filemanager folder at the root of the public folder `public/filemanager` and I inserted the javascript as followed. `external_filemanager_path:"/filemanager/",` I can see the button and everything but when I click on the button the modal comes up with this error message `/filemanager/dialog.php was not found on this server.` I guess it has something to do with the relative path? I am not sure what else it should be. I tried `/public/filemanager` also and still didn't work.

Comment: Is this being served from a linux box? What are the permissions of the  /public/filemanager directory and its contents?

Comment: `/filemanager/dialog.php was not found on this server`. Looks like you are not setting the correct absolute path to filemanager directory

Comment: no this is being used on WAMP. Everything should have write access. @manix Yeah, I know that has to be it but I am not to familiar with the absolute path for the public directory as I use the blade template in my view to set the paths. But now that I think of it maybe I can just source one of those and copy and paste to see if that sticks.

Comment: Well that did it. I think I can manage from here. If anyone has any documentation on relative absolute file paths and how to correctly use them that would be very helpful to me

Comment: has filemanager a config file? If it does, then you can set the absolute path to this directory doing something like this: `"path" => public_path( ). 'filemanager/'`.

Comment: Yeah, the filemanager does have a config.php file. I will have to check that out. Thanks for the info!